# text files used in my project compatible with iPhone/ipad?

Tags: iphone, text-files

I have made an app where I am loading my table with data from a text file. I know, I could have used plists, but I am more comfortable with test files, as you don't have to worry about key names and all. I just wanted to be sure though, if the text files stored in my project will work fine once i load the app onto iPhone/ipad?? It works fine now when i run it on the mac, in the simulator. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your files will work fine. Iphone support `.txt`, `.html`, `.xml`, `.json` and other simplest text formats.